# MySQL delete common rows but limit rows

Tags: mysql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I want to limit the number of rows to delete during a loop. 
Below are the tables. Please note this is sample and both tables have 20+ columns and millions of rows  :

```
Table A1: 
ID  Name
1   Tony 
2   Andy
3   Nate 

A2
ID  Name
1   Tony 
2   Andy
```

I want to delete only 1 row at a time, and will use a loop to re-run the same sql. I tried :

```
delete from a1 where id  in (select id from a1 inner join a2 on a1.id = a2.id limit 1);
```

says :

> you cannot specify target table 'a1' for update in FROM clause.

Is there a way I can do this in mysql?

Comment: Why loop? Any specific reason?

Comment: Btw, I think you've been here long enough to know how Stack rolls. So many questions, and none accepted. Your interaction on solutions given also is left to be questionable.

Comment: See the linked question for how to solve the "cannot specify target table for update" problem. Use that solution and add `LIMIT` to it.

Comment: I don't think the linked duplicate is really a duplicate.  I'm pretty sure the right solution is to convert the subquery to a correlated subquery, which is not covered by that answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- got it. thanks for letting me know of something i overlooked.

Comment: @ArunSrini You're welcome and thanks. This makes it easy for people to know that the question was solved. In not doing so, others may think that the question(s) is/are still open/unsolved and may be tempted to post (more) answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why you would use a loop.  However I suspect you want a correlated subquery:

```
delete from a1
    where a1.id in (select a2.id from a2 where a1.id = a2.id limit 1);
```

Note:  The use of `limit` without `order by` looks really dangerous.  This will delete an *arbitrary* row for each `a1.id`.